# how to pass initial value of FileField to Formset (in Django)

Tags: django, django-forms

I am trying to populate a Django formset using data from a POST/FILE request. I am able to populate all the fields except the FileField. It seems that `initial` cannot be used to pass the request.FILE to the FormSet creator function. My question is how to pass the FILE to FormSet.

The model.py

```
class ArticleForm(forms.Form):
     docfile = forms.FileField()
     subject = forms.Charfield(max_length=128)

ArticleFormSet = formset_factory(ArticleForm, extra=2)
```

the views.py

```
formset = ArticleFormSet(request.POST, request.FILE)
#do some other work, and then re-display the POST data

data = formset.cleaned_data
formset = ArticleFormSet(initial=data)

return render_to_response('some.html',
                          {'formset':formset}
                         )
```

Answer (score 3):

You can not pass initial data to a file field.
The `<input type="file" />` will always be blank when the browser renders it.

To pass `request.FILES` to a formset, just specify it as the second argument after POST.

http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/#using-a-formset-in-views-and-templates

`FormSet(request.POST, request.FILES)`

Comment: More question: 
1. for the second display, the file uploaded in the first time is not in request.FILES. 
2. in this approach, the extra form will display error-message, because all the fields in extra forms are empty.
How to handle the above issues?

Comment: @englefly can you clarify? Code examples? Are you trying to display a second formset with preopulated data? You can **not** prepopulate HTML file uploads, period. Let me update my answer with some code.

Comment: @englefly OK, I see your point. You want to re-display the formset even without any errors for whatever reason. The problem still stands: you can not ever display a `input type='file'` element with prepopulated data.  You must process the file in the first successful POST attempt.

Comment: if we override the render function of widget, we could display a <code> input type='file'</code> element with prepopulated data as any html element, for example a label.

Answer (score 0):

You can not pass any initial values when you are working with file uploads.