# Django's ClearableFileInput widget doesn't pass initial ("Currently") value on submit

Tags: django, django-forms

My basic goal is to create a form (using `ModelForm`) prefilled with data from an existing database object, allow a user to modify those data, then save the submitted form as a *new* object.  (Sort of a "Copy" then "Paste With Modifications" setup.)  This works fine except with File Fields and the ClearableFileInput widget.

The answers to questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358356/django-forms-filefield-initial-field), [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680603/does-django-repopulate-file-fields-on-form-error), and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814104/how-to-pass-initial-value-of-filefield-to-formset-in-django) make it clear that file fields can't and shouldn't be populated with an initial value.

The Django docs, however, on the [ClearableFileInput](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/forms/widgets/#clearablefileinput) widget say:

> File upload input: `<input type='file' ...>`, with an additional checkbox input to clear the field's value, if the field is not required and has ***initial*** data.

(A bit confusing already, but I assume Django's referring to the *model* field having an initial value, whereas the `<input type='file' ...>` field is still blank?)

So if I use either this method:

```
>>> obj = Foo.objects.get(pk=1)
>>> obj.fooFile.name
u'files/foo1.txt'
>>> f = FooForm(instance=obj)
```

or this method:

```
f = FooForm(initial={'fooFile':Foo.objects.get(pk=1).fooFile})
```

to instantiate my form, the ClearableFileInput widget displays:

[Currently with clearing checkbox, Change... input http://phagesdb.org/static/formDisplay.png](http://phagesdb.org/static/formDisplay.png)

When the user submits the form without changing this field, however, the value from the "Currently" line seems to be totally lost to Django.  It doesn't appear to be in either `request.POST` or `form.cleaned_data`.  When I call `.is_valid()` and then `.save()` on my bound ModelForm, the file field ends up blank in the new object.

So:

1. Does the ClearableFileInput widget pass the "Currently" value or not?  If not, isn't the ClearableFileInput widget misleading and/or of very limited use?  I'd assume that the value returned would be the value in "Currently..." unless I use the "Change..." input.
2. How can I capture that value so it appears in my new object when I call `.save()`?  (Remember that I can't use `f = FooForm(request.POST, request.FILES, instance=obj)` because I want a new object, not a modified object.)

Comment: Make sure the currently field is a) in the form markup body and b) has name and value attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Place a hidden field in your form and prepopulate it with the path to the image you passed in as initial.  Then write a save method something like the following.

This will appear to the user as if the filefield is prepopulated, save the file to the new instance, and allow them to use the clear checkbox, or upload their own image.

```
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
def save(self, commit=True):
    insance = super(FormClass, self).save(False)
    if not instance.file_field and self.cleaned_data['file_field_path'] and not self.data.get('file_field-clear'):
        path = os.path.join(settings.MEDIA_ROOT, self.cleaned_data['file_field_path'])
        with open(path) as f:
            file_object = ContentFile(f.read())
            instance.file_field.save(self.cleaned_data['file_field_path'], file_object, False)

    if commit:
        insance.save()
    return insance
```