# How should I show a link of existing file in Form.FileField from a model but not using ModelForm?

Tags: django, django-forms

I've checked [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12479856/djangos-clearablefileinput-widget-doesnt-pass-initial-currently-value-on-s) which itself cites [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4358356/django-forms-filefield-initial-field), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680603/does-django-repopulate-file-fields-on-form-error), [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4814104/how-to-pass-initial-value-of-filefield-to-formset-in-django), and cannot get an answer from the above. Let me use the following model to make an example:

```
class Assignment(models.Model):
     file1 = models.FileField(upload_to='xxx')
     file2 = models.FileField(upload_to='yyy')
     other_val = models.CharField(...)  # not important
```

And the Form:

```
class AssignmentForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Assignment
        fields = ['file1', 'other_val']  # but not file2

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        ...
        another_assignment = # assume somehow I get another assignment object from database
        self.fields['file2'] = forms.FileField(initial=???)
```

I want to pass `another_assignment.file2` as the default value. I think it is possible because ModelForm is capable of showing a link of the previously uploaded file. It looks like this:

```
Currently: AssignmentTask_grading_script/grading_script_firing.py 
Change: [Choose File] no file chosen
```

My question is, in a customized Form or if I want to add another FileField in a ModelForm, how should I pass a Model.FileField so that it can show a link if the file exists?

Answer (score 1):

You can send you query in the form like:

```
assignement = Assignement.objects.get(pk=some_pk)

data = {
   'file1' : assignment.file1,
    ...... so on
}
```

and send it in your form like:

```
AssignmentForm(data)
```

Thats it.. it will give you the existing value of the field...